# visual studio 2010 ultimate designer error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have installed Visual studio 2010 ultimate and when I try to open any window form from my existing window application project it gives me designer error as "The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed."

here is the image
[image: The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed]

Call Stack error message image

[image: call stack error message]

it works fine if I create new window application project, but giving problem for existing projects. Please help

Comment: Please show some code for `ExtraServices.cs`

Comment: its giving me error in all the forms of project not only in this particular form ExtraServices.cs

Comment: There are other warnigs shown, try to resolve them first. Maybe they are the cause.

Comment: thanks joe I resolved the warnings and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Your question gives us very little to go on, considering you don't show us even a sample of the code that the designer is choking on.

My crystal ball tells me that you've created some custom control classes that inherit from other classes in your project. When the designer goes to load that custom control class, it tries to instantiate its base class, and so on up the inheritance hierarchy. If it doesn't find one of those base classes, it errors.

The solution is simple: make sure that you've built the application/library first, before trying to open any of its custom controls in the designer. That way, all of the dependencies exist and are available to the designer.

Another possible problem, along the same lines, is that your custom controls are using some functionality only available in the full version of the .NET Framework, but your project is set to target the Client Profile. To fix this, open your project's Properties window and change ".NET Framework 4.0 (Client Profile)" to ".NET Framework 4.0".

If none of that fixes the problem, the last glimmer I can see in my crystal ball is based off the name of the code file that you've shown us in the screenshot: `ExtraServices.cs`. That doesn't sound to me like the name of a control. It sounds like that's just a regular old class. If that's the case, you can't design it because there is nothing for the designer to display. The only code files that can be opened in the designer are those that inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` or one of its derived classes (e.g. `System.Windows.Forms.Form`). Just right-click on it and open it as a regular code file.